# How can i add a prefix in a single cell for multiple codes?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a country code in 1 column and multiple city codes in different column separated by comma, i want to prefix the country code to each city codes..

How can i do that?

Comment: For clarification, are you saying the city codes are in a single cell and separated by a comma? Now you want to add the prefix to EACH city code in that single cell? Is that correct? (It would be very helpful to have an example with this question.)

Answer (score 0):

First import them using comma as the separator.

Next use

> C2=CONCATENATE(A2,B2)

where A2 has the country code & B2 the city code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean this:

```
country  | city
---------+---------
1        | 1, 2, 3
2        | 4, 5
3        | 6, 7, 8, 9
```

output;

```
result
---------
11, 12, 13
24, 25
36, 37, 38, 39
```

If yes ? answer is : `=[@country]&SUBSTITUTE([@city];", ";", "&[@country])`

or If it's not in a table : `=A2&SUBSTITUTE(B2;", ";", "&A2)`